# Using and comparing Python types at run-time, when using typing model and the Optional modifier

Tags: python-typing

I am committed to using type annotations but I want to compare types, one a fundamental type and one an Optional[..] wrapped type. I think I need to look '*through*' the Optional[ ... ] type hint modifier. This is in Python 3.10.

My code example is below. I want to get the message "Yes they both can contain strings".

Is there a call I use to replace `type( my_optional_string )` that returns the underlying `str` type within?

```
    from typing import Optional

    my_string : str = ""
    my_optional_string : Optional[str] = ""

    if type(my_string) == type( my_optional_string ):
        print("Yes they both can contain strings")
    else:
        print("No, not stringy types")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no a universal and straightforward solution, but the result you want can be achieved using typing [introspection functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#introspection-helpers). In this case to obtain variable annotations we are forced to use their names in text form.

Like so:

```py
import sys
from typing import Optional, get_type_hints, get_args, get_origin, Union


def can_be_str(type_: type) -> bool:
    return type_ is str or (get_origin(type_) is Union and str in get_args(type_))


my_string: str = ""
my_optional_string: Optional[str] = None
my_int: int = 1
my_optional_int: Optional[int] = None

# get annotations for current module
type_hints = get_type_hints(sys.modules[__name__])

assert can_be_str(type_hints["my_string"]) is True
assert can_be_str(type_hints["my_optional_string"]) is True
assert can_be_str(type_hints["my_int"]) is False
assert can_be_str(type_hints["my_optional_int"]) is False
```